# Calculate the mean over a mixed data structure

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of lists that looks something like:

```
data = [
    [1., np.array([2., 3., 4.]), ...],
    [5., np.array([6., 7., 8.]), ...],
    ...
]
```

where each of the internal lists is the same length and contains the same data type/shape at each entry. I would like to calculate the mean over corresponding entries and return something of the same structure as the internal lists. For example, in the above case (assuming only two entries) I want the result to be:

```
[3., np.array([4., 5., 6.]), ...]
```

What is the best way to do this with Python?

Comment: Are those (number and 1D numpy array the only possible values? Will there be other data types and/or further nested arrays?

Comment: Actually, they could be N-dimensional arrays. The key thing is that the mean is taken over the corresponding element in each array (as in the example), rather than over the full array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a list, so a list comprehension seems like a natural option. Even if it were a numpy array, given that it's a jagged array, it wouldn't benefit from being wrapped in an ndarray anyway, so a list comp would still be the best option, in my opinion.

Anyway, use `zip()` to "transpose" `data` and call `np.mean()` in a loop to find mean along the first axis.

```py
[np.mean(x, axis=0) for x in zip(*data)]
# [3.0, array([4., 5., 6.]), array([[2., 2.], [2., 2.]])]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a list exactly the same as the one shown in the example, you can do it with the following code.
First we declare some variables to store our results:

```py
number_sum = 0
list_sum = np.array([0,0,0])
```

It is important that you initialize the values ​​you need to 0 in `list_sum`. That is, if the data array contains 5 elements, that array should be: `list_sum = np.array([0,0,0,0,0])`.

The next step is to perform the sum of all elements in data. First we add the int values ​​and then we perform the sum of each element of the list as follows:

```py
for number, nparray in data:
    number_sum += number
    for index, item in enumerate(nparray):
        list_sum[index] += item
```

Since we know how the variable `data` is structured (each input is made up of an int value and an np.array) we can do the addition that way. Although be careful with the computational complexity because in examples with longer arrays it could become very high in terms of complexity, since two for loops are being nested.

Finally, you can check that if you divide the sum of the elements by the length of `data` you get the desired value:

```py
print(number_sum/len(data))
print(list_sum/len(data))
```

Now you just have to add those two new values ​​to a new list. I hope it helps, greetings and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
import numpy as np

data = [
    [1., np.array([2., 3., 4.]), np.array([[1., 1.], [1., 1.]])],
    [5., np.array([6., 7., 8.]), np.array([[3., 3.], [3., 3.]])],
]

number_of_samples = len(data)
number_of_elements = len(data[0])
means = []
for ielement in range(number_of_elements):
    mean_list = []
    for isample in range(number_of_samples):
        mean_list.append(data[isample][ielement])
    mean_list = np.stack(mean_list)
    mean = mean_list.mean(axis=0)
    means.append(mean)
print(means)
```

but is a bit ugly, nests a `for` loops, and does not seem to be very pythonic. Any improvements over this are welcomed.